# The advantages of using AppDomain in C# with Proxy Pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, appdomain

I have code to implement [GoF's proxy pattern in C#](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx). The code has MathProxy for calculating arithmetic functions.

The left side example is one implementation, and the right side is the better one for C# (.NET) with  AppDomain.

What benefits can I expect using AppDomain especially with Proxy Pattern?

```
public MathProxy()
{
    // Create Math instance in a different AppDomain
    var ad =  AppDomain.CreateDomain("MathDomain", null, null);

    var o = ad.CreateInstance(
        "DoFactory.GangOfFour.Proxy.NETOptimized",
        "DoFactory.GangOfFour.Proxy.NETOptimized.Math");
    _math = (Math)o.Unwrap();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any given Windows process that hosts the CLR can have one or more application domains defined that contain the executable code, data, metadata structures, and
resources. In addition to the protection guarantees built in by the process, an application domain further introduces the following guarantees:

- Faulty code within an application domain cannot adversely affect code running in a different application domain within the same process.
- Code running within an application domain cannot directly access resources in a different application domain.
- Code-specific configurations can be configured on a per application domain basis. For example, you can configure security-specific settings on a per application
  domain basis.

Comment: Would it make sense to use an app Domain with a WCF Service? Or should the service provide by definition the needed isolation?

Answer (score 1):

`AppDomain` provides isolation boundary in CLR same as a `process` provides a isolation boundary at operating system level

Answer (score 1):

Difference between AppDomain and Process :

Process: 
When a user starts an application, memory and a whole host of resources are allocated for the application. The physical separation of this memory and resources is called a process. An application may launch more than one process. It's important to note that applications and processes are not the same thing at all.

AppDomain :
Microsoft also introduced an extra layer of abstraction/isolation called an AppDomain. The AppDomain is not a physical isolation, but rather a logic isolation within the process. Since more than one AppDomain can exist in a process, we get some benefits. For example, until we had an AppDomain, processes that needed to access each other's data had to use a proxy, which introduced extra code and overhead. By using an AppDomain, it is possible to launch several applications within the same process. The same sort of isolation that exists with processes is also available for AppDomains. Threads can execute across application domains without the overhead of inter process communication. This is all encapsulated within the AppDomain class. Any time a namespace is loaded in an application, it is loaded into an AppDomain. The AppDomain used will be the same as the calling code unless otherwise specified. An AppDomain may or may not contain threads, which is different to processes.

Why You Should Use AppDomains :  [Read Post](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/ThreadingDotNet.aspx?msg=2557762#xx2557762xx)

Good use case scenario for AppDomains :
"NUnit was written by .NET Framework experts. If you look at the NUnit source, you see that they knew how to dynamically create AppDomains and load assemblies into these domains. Why is a dynamic AppDomain important? What the dynamic AppDomain lets NUnit do is to leave NUnit open, while permitting you to compile, test, modify, recompile, and retest code without ever shutting down. You can do this because NUnit shadow copies your assemblies, loads them into a dynamic domain, and uses a file watcher to see if you change them. If you do change your assemblies, then NUnit dumps the dynamic AppDomain, recopies the files, creates a new AppDomain, and is ready to go again."

Entire info borrowed from [Sacha Barbers article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26148/Beginners-Guide-to-Threading-in-NET-Part-1-of-n#AppDomains)